# Set ComboBox in Specific Cell in DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview, combobox

I've seen multiple threads about combobox's in DataGridView rows/columns but nothing really focused on just one cell.  I'm trying to loop through all the cells in the DataGridView and when it recognizes a Parameter that is supposed to have the options On/Off, it loads a ComboBox in.

The code I've been working on is:

```
 dataGridView1.DataSource = typeof(Parameter);
 dataGridView1.DataSource = _paramList;

     foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewCell ce in row.Cells)
            {
                foreach (Information i in _information)
                {
                    if (ce.Value.ToString() == "Light")
                    {
                        DataGridViewComboBoxCell c = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();
                        c.Items.Add("On");
                        c.Items.Add("Off");

             dataGridView1.Rows[ce.RowIndex].Cells[ce.ColumnIndex] = c;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

It throws an error "Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute." which I'm guessing has to do with it populating the cell with a combobox and trying to continue the foreach statement?  Any ideas/change to fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Foreach loops handle enumerators for you, they get this error (enumeration cannot continue, collection modified) quite easily.  You can get around this by using for loops. I tested the below (tried with foreach first - no dice), and we seem to be good.

Also of note - I had to set the actual cell value to null before setting the new item. Without this, I got an error "value of datagridcomboboxcell is not valid" (or something similar).

*Edit: I left out your third nested loop. It's not necessary for this proof of concept. This simply adds the combobox to 100% of cells.*

Including all of my testing code for reproduction:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp5
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private DataGridView oDg;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        CreateGrid();
        this.Shown += Form1_Shown;
    }

    private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TestIt();
    }

    private void TestIt()
    {
        //works
        for (int i = 0;i < oDg.RowCount; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0;j< oDg.ColumnCount; j++)
            {
                oDg.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value = null; //this is important.
                DataGridViewComboBoxCell c = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();
                c.Items.Add("On");
                c.Items.Add("Off");
                oDg.Rows[i].Cells[j] = c;  
            }
        }    
        //does not work
        //foreach (DataGridViewRow row in oDg.Rows)
        //{
        //    foreach (DataGridViewCell ce in row.Cells)
        //    {
        //        oDg.Rows[ce.RowIndex].Cells[ce.ColumnIndex].Value = null;
        //        DataGridViewComboBoxCell c = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();
        //        c.Items.Add("On");
        //        c.Items.Add("Off");
        //        oDg.Rows[ce.RowIndex].Cells[ce.ColumnIndex] = c;
        //    }
        //}
    }
    private void CreateGrid()
    {
        oDg = new DataGridView();
        oDg.Width = 800;
        oDg.Height = 800;
        oDg.DataSource = CreateDataSource();
        this.Controls.Add(oDg);
    }
    private DataTable CreateDataSource()
    {
        DataTable oDt = new DataTable();
        for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            DataColumn col = new DataColumn(i.ToString(),typeof (String));
            oDt.Columns.Add(col);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 99; i++)
        {
            DataRow rw = oDt.NewRow();
            for (int j = 0;j < oDt.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                rw[j] = j.ToString();
            }
            oDt.Rows.Add(rw);
        }
        return oDt;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Hi, I think this code above will populate the whole DataGridView with ComboBox's where as I am trying to populate a specific cell in a row.  ex. Lights | **ComboBox (On/Off)** |  The reason I had the third foreach was to loop through to see if any cell in the datagridview matched the string "Lights"

Comment: I'm not writing your code for you, I'm solving your problem.  I edited it 33 minutes before your comment.  Check the post for italics.

Comment: Gotcha.  I implemented for loops instead of foreach and it works now.  I also had to make sure to +1 to the j interval when declaring it equal to C to make sure it got the cell to the right of the found cell.  Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear it.